# How to find the name of the edittext in focus

Tags: android

I want to find the id of the edittext whose text is changed in a toast message.
I AM A begginer please help me.
I want to use the alternate of Event.Target(that is in .net)in android

The layout is the following containg two edit text

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.pal.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10" />
     <requestFocus />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/a1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </FrameLayout>
```

.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText s1,s2;
int f,f1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
s1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1);
s1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+s1,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

s2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.a2);
s2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        f1=s2.getId();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+s2,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

}
```

In the .java file where a toast message is there plz let me know what can be used instead of s1 and s2

Comment: edit texts like any other views don't have any names

Comment: Try [getCurrentFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29) for parent layout